# Filter Prometheus Kubernetes Data

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, amazon-eks

I am using a Helm chart on a Kubernetes cluster (https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus) and sending the results to Amazon Managed Prometheus.

Using Grafana I have found a majority of the metrics are for "apiserver" which we don't used for our Grafana dashboards.

How can I filter the apiserver metrics so that are not pushed to the remote-write? (similar for etcd)